# Is this a bug or means something, if i see grass deep underground

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

This is about 60 blocks underground, close to the bottom of the world where there is **no** day light anywhere, with no exit to the surface. Here is a picture of what I mean:

[image]

Should it be like this? Why didn't I see this before then? Is it a bug with terrain generation?

Just to note I'm running minecraft 1.8.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. This is not a bug. In Minecraft, grass may spawn far below ground level during world generation, upon grass blocks underground if there are any.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie "during world generation" - what do you mean? "world generation" is infinite in minecraft. I was playing it for years before i saw grass and flowers underground in 1.8.1 first time. Are you sure?

Comment: @DmitrijA when a new chunk is loaded, that hasn't been loaded before, that counts as "world generation". When your world is first generated, that is the most common reference to "world generation". As for the genuinity of this, I also can attest to this. I have seen it happen, though rarely.

Comment: This occurs in older versions as well, such as 1.7, 1.6, 1.5, etc